# How to use In clause in JPQL query with subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpql

I have a entity classes as below

ExportMO.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DATAEXPORTTEMPLATE")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ExportTemplateMO.getTemplatesByUser", query = "SELECT DISTINCT template FROM ExportTemplateMO template " +
        "join template.fields exportFields WHERE template.eId IN (SELECT S1.dcid FROM SchoolMO S1 join S1.fields S2 WHERE S2.dcid = :userDCID)")
})
public class ExportMO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATATEMPLATEID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long templateId;


    @Column(name = "EID", nullable = true)
    private Long eId;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="templateMO", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<ExportFieldMO> fields;

}
```

SchoolMO.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SCHOOLSTAFF")

    public class SchoolMO implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "DCID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long dcid;

        @Column(name = "ID", unique = true) 
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "USERS_DCID", unique = false, nullable = false)    
 @JoinColumn(name="USERS_DCID",referencedColumnName="USERS_DCID",nullable=false)
            private Long users_dcid;

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="users_dcid", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<SchoolStaffLeanMO> fields;
    }
```

Can someone help me how to use this using the IN clause for subquery.
If i try to use the same '=' instead of 'IN' i am able to get the results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oooh, I wonder what happens when you invoke that query, and what SQL is invoked. Maybe if you do that, and look at the JPA providers log you'd understand more?

Comment: Your join on `template.fields exportFields` is not re-used. Instead of an `IN` clause, how about a join like `SELECT DISTINCT template 
FROM ExportTemplateMO template, SchoolMO S1 
JOIN S1.fields S2 
WHERE template.eId = S1.dcid 
AND S2.dcid = :userDCID`? I forgot if multiple JOIN is allowed in JPQL

Comment: @Al1 I cant do that but my requirement is little different..

Comment: Just want to check whether in SchoolMO.java I have correctly declared the annotations or not.. I am actually trying in subquery similar to the below SQL SELECT S1.DCID FROM SCHOOLSTAFF S1 INNER JOIN SCHOOLSTAFF S2 ON S1.USERS_DCID = S2.USERS_DCID WHERE S2.DCID='2'